# Nested views with nested states in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

I'm trying to make nested states, but something is wrong and I can't figure out why.

I have these states in my angular app:

```
/client (list clients)
/client/:id (show client)
/client/new (new client)
```

And now, I'm trying to do:

```
/client/:id/task (list clients tasks)
/client/:id/task/new (create new task for this client)
/client/:id/task/:idTask (show the client task)
```

All the states are working, but the `task` states is not changing the content.

My *index.html* with the `ui-view "main"`:

```
<section id="container">
    <header></header>
    <sidebar></sidebar>
    <section class="main-content-wrapper" ng-class="{'main':collapse}">
        <section id="main-content">
            <div ui-view="main"></div>
        </section>
    </section>
</section>
```

My *client.tpl.html* with the ui-view "content":

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active">Clients</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
```

My app states:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('/', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/app/application/application.tpl.html',
        abstract: true
    })

    // CLIENT
    .state('client', {
        url: '/client',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'main': {
                templateUrl: '/app/client/client.tpl.html',
                controller: 'ClientController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('client.list', {
        url: '/list',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: '/app/client/client.list.tpl.html',
                controller: 'ClientListController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('client.new', {
        url: '/new',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: '/app/client/client.new.tpl.html',
                controller: 'ClientNewController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('client.show', {
        url: '/:id',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: '/app/client/client.show.tpl.html',
                controller: 'ClientShowController',
            }
        }
    })
```

Tasks states

```
    // TASKS
    .state('client.details', {
        url: '/:idClient',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: '/app/task/task.tpl.html',
                controller: 'TaskController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('client.details.task', {
        url: '/task',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: '/app/task/task.list.tpl.html',
                controller: 'TaskListController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('client.details.task.new', {
        url: '/new',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: '/app/task/task.new.tpl.html',
                controller: 'TaskNewController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('client.details.task.show', {
        url: '/:idTask',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: '/app/task/task.show.tpl.html',
                controller: 'TaskShowController'
            }
        }
    });
```

So, when I click to go to:

```
/client
/client/:id
/client/new
```

Everything works fine, the content change, but, when I click to go to:

```
/client/:id/task
/client/:id/task/:idTask
/client/:id/task/new
```

The content don't change, actually, the content gets empty.

---

UPDATE 1

The link to the task list is in my sidebar, sidebar is a directive:

Directive:

```
.directive('sidebar', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/common/partials/sidebar.html'
    };
}])
```

Template:

```
<aside class="sidebar" ng-class="{'sidebar-toggle':collapse}" ng-controller="SidebarController as sidebar">
    <div id="leftside-navigation" class="nano">
        <ul class="nano-content">
            <li class="active">
                <a href ui-sref="home"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><span>Home</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu">
                <a href ng-click="toggle()">
                    <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                    <span>Clients</span>
                    <i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
                </a>
                <ul style="height: {{height}}px; overflow: hidden;">
                    <li ng-repeat="client in session.clients">
                        <a href ui-sref="client.details.task({id:client.id})">{{client.name}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</aside>
```

The link in `ui-sref` is: `/client/10/task`

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution there is surprisingly simple, but the concept behind could be a bit challenging.

So the state definition should be like this

Client root state is without any change. It does inject its view into `ui-view="main"` of the root state *(index.html)*

```
// CLIENT
.state('client', {
    ...
    views: {
        'main': {
            templateUrl: '/app/client/client.tpl.html',
            ...
        }
    }
})
```

Now, we have first level children. They will target `ui-view="content"` of their parent *(client and its template injected into `ui-view="main"`)*

```
.state('client.list', {
    views: {
        'content': {
    ....
})
.state('client.new', {
    url: '/new',
    views: {
        'content': {
    ...
})
...
```

So until now, everything is working. Below is a change. We try again inject our templates into `ui-view="content"` - good. But it is not defined in our parent. It is in our **grand-parent** - a `Client` state. So we are skipping one level. We have to use absolute naming for view name targeting

```
// TASKS
.state('client.details.task', {
    views: {
        // wrong
        'content': {
        // correct
        'content@client': {         
})
.state('client.details.task.new', {
    views: {
        // wrong
        'content': {
        // correct
        'content@client': {         
    }
})
...
```

*Now it should be clear. If not, maybe this could help a bit. The first level children, would work even with this state definition*

```
.state('client.list', {
    views: {
        // working
        'content': {
        // also working
        'content@client': {
    ....
})
```

*Because we just used absolute naming - where the it is done for us out of the box (syntactic sugar). For more and even better explanation, please, see documentation:*

#### [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

small cite:

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of **`viewname@statename`**, where viewname is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. contact.item. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax.
>
> For example, the previous example could also be written as:

```
.state('report',{
    views: {
      'filters@': { },
      'tabledata@': { },
      'graph@': { }
    }
})
```

Comment: thank you so much! Your answer was awesome!!! I understood everything and you're right, is simple but a bit challenge do understand. Thank you again! =)

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow ;) Enjoy amazing `UI-Router` ;)